# Python socket module doesn't work very well, how to fix "[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: python, sockets

I write a small program to test my understanding of the socket module, but there is a problem that I dont know how to fix,here is the file of the client

```
    class Apple:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.color = x
        self.taste = y
a = Apple("yellow", "good")

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg):
    client.send(pickle.dumps(msg))
send(a)
```

and here is the file of the server

```
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

a = 0
def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        data = pickle.loads(conn.recv(4096))
        a = data
        if data == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
            connected = False

        conn.send("Msg received".encode(FORMAT))
    conn.close()


def start():
    server.listen(2)
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")

print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

It return such an error:
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

WHy is that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever blame the tool for things you do not understand.  The Python socket module works just fine.  Your server is trying to send a response after receiving, but your client exits immediately after sending  That "forcibly closes" the socket, which causes an error in the server.